# 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' error with Hello Analytics script

Tags: python, google-analytics-api

I'm only trying to use the "Hello Analytics API: Python quickstart for service accounts" script and I have the following error : `NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__`

I've simply copy and past the code and replace `service_account_email` and
`key_file_location`

Here is the code :

```
"""A simple example of how to access the Google Analytics API."""

import argparse

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

import httplib2
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import file
from oauth2client import tools



def get_service(api_name, api_version, scope, key_file_location,
                service_account_email):
  """Get a service that communicates to a Google API.

  Args:
    api_name: The name of the api to connect to.
    api_version: The api version to connect to.
    scope: A list auth scopes to authorize for the application.
    key_file_location: The path to a valid service account p12 key file.
    service_account_email: The service account email address.

  Returns:
    A service that is connected to the specified API.
  """

  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(
    service_account_email, key_file_location, scopes=scope)

  http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

  # Build the service object.
  service = build(api_name, api_version, http=http)

  return service


def get_first_profile_id(service):
  # Use the Analytics service object to get the first profile id.

  # Get a list of all Google Analytics accounts for this user
  accounts = service.management().accounts().list().execute()

  if accounts.get('items'):
    # Get the first Google Analytics account.
    account = accounts.get('items')[0].get('id')

    # Get a list of all the properties for the first account.
    properties = service.management().webproperties().list(
        accountId=account).execute()

    if properties.get('items'):
      # Get the first property id.
      property = properties.get('items')[0].get('id')

      # Get a list of all views (profiles) for the first property.
      profiles = service.management().profiles().list(
          accountId=account,
          webPropertyId=property).execute()

      if profiles.get('items'):
        # return the first view (profile) id.
        return profiles.get('items')[0].get('id')

  return None


def get_results(service, profile_id):
  # Use the Analytics Service Object to query the Core Reporting API
  # for the number of sessions within the past seven days.
  return service.data().ga().get(
      ids='ga:' + profile_id,
      start_date='7daysAgo',
      end_date='today',
      metrics='ga:sessions').execute()


def print_results(results):
  # Print data nicely for the user.
  if results:
    print 'View (Profile): %s' % results.get('profileInfo').get('profileName')
    print 'Total Sessions: %s' % results.get('rows')[0][0]

  else:
    print 'No results found'


def main():
  # Define the auth scopes to request.
  scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']

  # Use the developer console and replace the values with your
  # service account email and relative location of your key file.
  service_account_email = 'myemailhere'
  key_file_location = 'myp12here'

  # Authenticate and construct service.
  service = get_service('analytics', 'v3', scope, key_file_location,
    service_account_email)
  profile = get_first_profile_id(service)
  print_results(get_results(service, profile))


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

update stack trace :

```
View (Profile): website.fr
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 108, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 104, in main
    print_results(get_results(service, profile))
  File "test.py", line 85, in print_results
    print 'Total Sessions: %s' % results.get('rows')[0][0]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: on which line does it occur?

Comment: yes, complete stack trace would be helpful!

Comment: Question updated ! I feel like I'm lost between my view, account and property.

Comment: Have you tried it with only one [0] or without it at all ? just: print 'Total Sessions: %s' % results.get('rows')[0] or print 'Total Sessions: %s' % results.get('rows') , this at least what the error is about. If you do not know when it has the dimensions you could try to build a try catch block around it

Comment: so the error I have is not about the script but It's more about the way I use it. I have a mistake somewhere related to the configuration of my Google Analytics account... ?